# Excel VBA Copy Paste Images

Tags: excel, vba

I have a "Meeting Model" sheet consisting of macro-embedded buttons at the top. When the user clicks a button, a range of information will be transferred, including snippets of images and shapes from a different worksheet. In my code, I've specified which range of cells I want the information to be pasted. Each command button has a code to clear the content including the images before pasting.

```
Sub copyReadiness()



Dim pic As Picture
For Each pic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
If Not Application.Intersect(pic.TopLeftCell, Range("I20:Y2000")) Is Nothing Then
        pic.Delete
    End If
Next pic

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
'Copies data from items sheet then pastes to test sheet
Sheets("Readiness Meeting").Select
Range("A1:Q2000").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("MeetingModel").Select
Range("I20").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I am expecting that each time the button is clicked, the prior content including images (snippets of shapes) and content will be removed before pasting. The information is being cleared. However, the snippets are being pasted on top of each other every time. Please advise what adjustments I need to make to get that fixed.

Thank you,
Rie

Comment: Have you tried `...As Shape` and `...In Activesheet.Shapes`?

Comment: After Dim pic As Picture, put "Dim Shapes As Shapes", and after Range("I20").Select put "ActiveSheet.Shapes Paste"?